# ubuntu doesnt show image in html

Tags: html, css, ubuntu, background-image

I have developed a web page using windows and it works fine. but when I want to upload in on the web using ubuntu, one image is not shown. here is the css code:

```
start-page {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: url('../img/background/start.jpg') #c0c0c0 bottom center fixed no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Comment: It's a permission issue. First, check this issue.

Comment: It's mostly due to permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ubuntu navigate to the folder and grant all access to all content by:

`chmod -R 777 .`

If that solves the problem, then you know it's a permission issue.

Note: In general it's not safe to grant all access to all users especially in production.

P.S. another easy way would be just to upload your images on a third party (like amazon S3) as it's a much better practice to host your assets somewhere other than your main server anyway.

Comment: Thank you Rudy! It still doesn't show the image. I have started using S3 to upload the files.  :*

Answer (score -1):

You also can use the whole path in the browser, sometimes the Ubuntu server doesn't recognize the image and we have to install another commands, but you can try it with the file at the beginning (`'file:///home/...'`) and the rest of your location, something like the following:

```css
background: url('file:///home/youruser/img/background/start.jpg') #c0c0c0 bottom center fixed no-repeat;
```